Как добавить перенос фигурных скобок на новую строку в VS Code?
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии enter открывающая фигурная скобка автоматически переносилась на следующую строку в Visual Studio Code для языков c и c++?
int foo(){
//было так
}

int foo()
{
//стало так
}


Оно тебе зачем? Будет правильнее работать, или быстрее?

Не уверен, что можно именно в таком виде настроить. Проще поставить автоформатирование всего файла при сохранении, либо приучить себя руками жать Enter перед скобкой.

не знаю ничего на счёт VS, но в VScode идут файлы конфигурации JSON, в которых, если я не ошибаюсь, можно было настроить подобное поведение. Может, что-то подобное было перенесено и на студию

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934072/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line-in-c-sharp-and-c-whil
